# Clean install 18.04 on top of existing 14.04 in double boot Win 7 + Ubuntu 14.04LTS + Grub

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

My system is a dual boot Win 7 / Ubuntu 14.04LTS / Grub.

*My objective is to have a fresh install 18.04 on top of the existing 14.04, given there is the other OS*.

I found several sources, but mostly dealing with 16.04 -> 18.04.
I guess it should work right away.

**Should I take any special consideration to make it work, different from a regular installation of 18.04 on a Win 7 taking up the whole disk?**

(Now I will already have the extra partitions that the Ubuntu installer creates, etc.)

Comment: Indeed I meant backup. 

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Possible duplicate of [Clone backup/restore Ubuntu 18.04 in a dual boot Win/Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066198/clone-backup-restore-ubuntu-18-04-in-a-dual-boot-win-ubuntu)

Comment: @user68186 - They are not the same question. I explicitly took care of separating the questions because they are different (but related). This one deals with installing one version on top of the other (while the companion Win is 7), The other deals with recovering a backup (while the companion Win is 10). I hoped to make it clear. Please let me know if, with this remark, they still look the same.

Comment: I have all valued files in Dropbox so am free to install or upgrade at will ... I strongly suggest you do similar ... there are way too many unknowables to act on blind faith

Comment: @ScottStensland - That is a safety precaution in case things fail. I would take some such precautions.